# How to create generic Map interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a Map interface in TypeScript but I cannot seem to figure out how to constrain the property accessor to please the compiler

### Desired Interface

```
export interface IMap<I extends string | number, T> {
  [property: I]: T;
}
```

### Error:

> An index signature type must be 'string' or 'number'

Comment: you're trying to create a generic.

Comment: indeed you can only do this with `string` or `number` as of today

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are allowed to define both a string and numeric index signature.

From the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.9.4):

> An object type can contain at most one string index signature and one numeric index signature.

So you can do this:

```
interface IMap<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
    [index: number]: T;
}
```

Is that what you were after?

Also, when you define only a string index signature:

> Specifically, in a type with a string index signature of type T, all properties and **numeric** index signatures must have types that are assignable to T.

And so:

```
class Foo {
    [index: string]: number;
}

let f = new Foo();

f[1] = 1; //OK

f[6] = "hi"; //ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

Comment: Thanks, however I was looking to be able to use the interface as `IMap<number, string>` or `IMap<string, string>` defining the index type per usage. It appears this is not possible.

Comment: Ah, OK. Yeah, you are right. You could create two separate interfaces, but that sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yeah, there's only two types it could be. If TypeScript allowed indexing via Enums there'd be more need for a generic.