# Strategy - string to type in typescript

Tags: dictionary, typescript, strategy-pattern

I'm using typescript, and I want to map a string to a type so I can make instances of certain type based on a string I have.

I'm writing to node.js

For example - I get from a DB the value "range" and for that case I want to use my class "RangeFilter", but in the case of the value "size" I want to use the class "SizeFilter". They all inherit from the interface "IFilter".

So is there a way to map (create a dictionary) between the values to the type

So it could be like this

> map: {key: string, value: IFilter};
>
> Return new map["range"] //returns RangeFilter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically loading a typescript class (reflection for typescript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript)

Comment: Since I'm writing to node.js I don't have window object, and I can't search inside it of my object

Comment: so maybe you should better argument your question, sorry

Comment: You're right I'll add it

Comment: See this question on creating a TS map interface http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686200/how-to-create-generic-map-interface-in-typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way.
Basically all you need to know is that the type of a class `MyClass` is: `{ new(): MyClass }`.

Then you can do:

```
interface IFilter {}

type FilterConstructor = { new(): IFilter };

class RangeFilter implements IFilter {}

class SizeFilter implements IFilter {}

let ctors: { [key: string]: FilterConstructor } = {};
ctors["range"] = RangeFilter;
ctors["size"] = SizeFilter;

function factory<T extends IFilter>(key: string): T {
    let ctor = ctors[key];

    return ctor == null ? null : new ctor() as T;
}

let rangeFilter: RangeFilter = factory("range");
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IFilter%20%7B%7D%0A%0Atype%20FilterConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%20new()%3A%20IFilter%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20RangeFilter%20implements%20IFilter%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20SizeFilter%20implements%20IFilter%20%7B%7D%0A%0Alet%20ctors%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20FilterConstructor%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0Actors%5B%22range%22%5D%20%3D%20RangeFilter%3B%0Actors%5B%22size%22%5D%20%3D%20SizeFilter%3B%0A%0Afunction%20factory%3CT%20extends%20IFilter%3E(key%3A%20string)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%09let%20ctor%20%3D%20ctors%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%09%0A%09return%20ctor%20%3D%3D%20null%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20new%20ctor()%20as%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20rangeFilter%3A%20RangeFilter%20%3D%20factory(%22range%22)%3B))

Comment: Thank you ! Helped a lot